# Unable to save matlab figure with transparent background

Tags: matlab

The exported figure (which is transparent) is saved with white background.

````
```x = 0:.1:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
% save to transparented image
figure;
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',4);
set(gcf, 'color', 'none');    
set(gca, 'color', 'none');
exportgraphics(gcf,'transparent.eps',...   % since R2020a
    'ContentType','vector',...
    'BackgroundColor','none')'''
````

What could be wrong?

Comment: Depending on your application, you might just use saveas(fig, 'fig.svg'). Most figures are saved with a white background but this can be deleted in any vector graphics editor (e.g. illustrator, inkscape)

Comment: The problem is that some times it works, I can not pinpoint the root cause

Comment: Post one example for which you get the desired result and one example or which you get the undesired result